# Z-index Not able get it proper

Tags: wordpress, css

I was trying to keep a logo above a slider but i was unable to set the z-index properly

I have tried  Z-index increasing order but not able to get it right

the link is 
 http://design3web.in/law-firm/

their is a image back of the Head-slider i want to get it on front

I have Given Z-index for slider as 1 
and z-index for logo is 10 but this didn't work

And i also want to make the image responsive the thing

```
margin-top: -400px;
height: auto;
 z-index: 100;
position: absolute;
max-width: 90%;
```

but still the image is not totally responsive

**Also have problem with the image moving upwards or downwards as it is responsive**

Comment: adding position: relative, and higher z-index to image make it done

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the `z-index:10001` also set the image to `position:absolute` then set the `top:` to the correct value.

Check it out - http://jsbin.com/itiviw/4

Comment: yes thanks can u tell me the whats with the responsive problem

Comment: actually can u help setting the postion of the logo ? as the image is responsive it is moving upwards or downwards

Answer (score 0):

css

```
#logo {
font-size: 2em;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: -0.05em;
line-height: 1em;
margin: 0 0 1em;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

}

Add `position: relative;` & `z-index: 1;`

Answer (score 0):

If you set the **position** to '**relative**' as well as setting the z-index it will work.

```
<img src="http://design3web.in/law-firm/files/2012/08/Untitled-1.png" style="
margin-top: -500px;
max-width: 80%;   height: auto;
z-index: 100;
position: relative;">
```

Comment: Correct can u help me in positioning it  as it moving with respective to screen size

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with this before, and my solution was to wrap everything in a div, set the position to relative, and set the wrapped div z-index to 1, then adjust the other divs inside accordingly.